# Python: run shell script with manual input

Tags: python, shell

For example, the shell script takes an integer at a prompt and returns it.

```
Enter an integer:
--> 3
3
```

I'm using `subprocess.check_call(["./myScript"])` to run the shell script. How can I automate sending the `"3"` in as in the example above? So far all my searching has only recovered how to run a script with command line arguments, not this kind of manual input.

Comment: How do you get the input (the "3")? Are you using `input()`, `raw_input()` ect.? And what Python version do you have?

Comment: OP is not taking input from python, he/she wants to pass input from python to shell script that prompts for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the earlier answer explained [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) can be used to create process that can be interacted with [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). `communicate` takes string as a parameter that will be passed to the created process and returns tuple `(stdout, stderr)`. Below is a short example of two Python scripts communicating with it:

**Child**

```
nums = raw_input()
print sum((int(n) for n in nums.split()))
```

**Parent**

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate('3 4 5')
print 'From other process: ' + out
```

**Output**

```
From other process: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [`subprocess.Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) function. The docs are quite expressive.